# ¿Cómo hacer que el ancho de las columnas del DataGridView se adapte a su contenido?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un formulario en el que utilizo un `DataGridView` para presentar los registros de la base de datos.

El punto es que el `DataGridView` no me presenta todo el nombre de la columna y tengo que agrandarlo manualmente. Por eso **me gustaría que el ancho de las columnas se auto adapte al tamaño del texto que posee**.

Aquí les dejo una imagen del Formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con:

```
DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Columms.Weith = AutoSizeColumnsMode.AutoZise
```

Pero recibo errores, alguien tiene alguna idea de ¿Cómo hacer que el ancho de las columnas del DataGridView se adapte a su contenido?.

Comment: this.NombreDeTuDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

Comment: gracias @fredyfx me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: de nada hermano, éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad DataGridViewColumn.Width.
Por ejemplo:

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].Width = 100;
```

Mas información: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx

Edito: para que sea automatico.

```
dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMo‌​de.Fill);
```

Comment: lo que necesito es que el ancho de  las columnas se adapten automáticamente a su contenido.

Comment: Intenta con dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);

Comment: me funciono con fill, puedes modificar tu respuesta para marcarla como la mejor.

Answer (score 4):

Para ajustar el tamaño de las columnas y las celdas, yo uso las siguientes líneas:

```
// Ajustar tamaño de columnas y celdas.
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Answer (score 2):

O usa las propiedades del gridview
Saludos

[image: Yo lo hice desde las propiedades]

Answer (score 2):

Si utilizas la propiedad autofill, esta te creara columnas de un solo tamaño, pero si quieres que alguna de estas columnas sea mas grande yo agrego esta propiedad y asi esta columna es mas grande segun el porcentaje que le diste.

```
DataGridViewBuscProd_BP.Columns(2).Width = 200%
```

unn ejemplo rapido seria si tienes u datagrid de 100de ancho y son 10 columnas, todas te quedaran de 10 de ancho cada una ,pero si quieres que la columna 2 sea mas grande entonces le agregas el valor en porcentaje. en el ejemplo fue de 200% osea dos veces su tamaño
obviamente el valor que le des de mas se descontara entre el resto de las columnas.