# ¿Definir ancho de columna de DataGridView cuando los cargo desde de un DataSet?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datatable

este me funciona bien

```
 
List mascota = new List();

dataGridView1.DataSource = mascota;
                    getEncabezado();


  private void getEncabezado()
    {
      dataGridView1.Columns["idmascota"].Visible = false;
      dataGridView1.Columns["nombremascota"].Width = 150;
      dataGridView1.Columns["nombremascota"].HeaderText = "Codigo";
    }
```

y quiero utilizar de esa misma forma

```
    OleDbConnection connection = Connection.getConnection();
               string sql = "SELECT idmascota,nombremascota,nombremascota  FROM Mascota";

               OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();

               dataadapter.Fill(ds, "DTMascota");
               dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
               dataGridView1.DataMember = "DTMascota";

               getEncabezado(); /// aqui hago el llamado a mi metodo para definir las caracteristicas del encabezado de mi dvgrid

               dataGridView1.Refresh();



    private void getEncabezado()
                {
                  dataGridView1.Columns["idmascota"].Visible = false;
                  dataGridView1.Columns["nombremascota"].Width = 150;    //**Error: Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en System.Windows.Forms.dll //  Información adicional: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.  *//
                  dataGridView1.Columns["nombremascota"].HeaderText = "Codigo";
                }
```

me sale este error y trate con estos dos metodos y no funciona [metodo1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla) , [metodo2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86315/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-que-el-ancho-de-las-columnas-del-datagridview-se-adapte-a-su-conteni)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que el títulos de tu pregunta no es el indicado, pues tu problema no es con el ancho, sino con una referencia nula. Ahora bien, como no brinca en la línea anterior significa que sí está bien la asignación del DataSource, por tanto lo primero que te recomiendo es que revises sí el valor "nombremascota" es correcto, revisa mayúsculas y minúsculas y que sí coincidan. Pon un punto de interrupción y revisa directamente en el objeto DataGridView las columnas que se asignaron.

Comment: @RandallSandoval hice todo, poner el punto interrupcion, revise las declaraciones y todo

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez y revisaste que el DataGridView tuviera dicha columna? Sino lo que te recomiendo es que asignes por medio del índice el tamaño. dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 150;

Comment: @RandallSandoval si señor, revise por el numero de columna y funcina los demas y el column sigue fallando

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez, ¿dónde estás llamando al método `getEncabezado();`? Creo que cuando se ejecuta esta línea `dataGridView1.DataSource = mascota;` se sobreescribe las columnas que pueda tener el dataGridView1. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta colocando los nombres de las columnas de la tabla `Mascota` según tu SELECT.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ya edita mi pregunta

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez, con el cambio que hiciste, ¿sigue saliendo el error? si es así, haz esta prueba: recorre las columnas que tenga el dataGridView1 e imprime los nombre de la columna. Yo creo que `nombremascota` no existe en ese punto donde sale el error.

Answer (score -1):

en mi experiencia la única vez que he visto una situación como esta es si tratas de setear el ".DataSource" antes de inicializar el DataGrid.

Recomiendo que setees tus propiedades a partir del evento .OnLoad del formulario.

puedes crear un metodo que se encargue de cargar la data, asignar el DataSource del grid y modificar las propiedades.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData() {
        OleDbConnection connection = Connection.getConnection();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Mascota";

        OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "DTMascota");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "DTMascota";

        getEncabezado();

        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        //Setting properties

        dataGridView1.Columns["idmascota"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["nombremascota"].Width = 150;    
        dataGridView1.Columns["nombrecota"].HeaderText = "Codigo";
    }
```

Comment: el problema no se está presentando a la hora de cargar los datos, sino a la hora de asignar el tamaño a una columna, incluso antes de donde salta el error se ejecuta una acción sobre una columna ya seteada por medio del DataSource.

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que veo, los datos obtenidos no tienen la columna "nombremascota" o no viene con ese nombre, por eso cuando quieres hacer referencia a la columna utilizando el nombre de columna como índice, te marca el error.

Has un debug y coloca un break justo en la línea donde te marca la excepción e inspecciona el contenido de. Columns para ver cuantas columnas y los nombres se crearon.

Comment: los nombres de las columnas coinciden, porque me acepta el cambiar el nombre `dataGridView1.Columns["nombremascota"].HeaderText = "Codigo";` este me acepta lo que me sale ese error es el ancho de la columna

Comment: Puedes poner los datos que salen al darle "ver detalle" en la ventana del a excepción? puedes ver incluso el seguimiento de los métodos que se llamaron antes de ocurrir la excepción.